# Echo without leading whitespace?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, echo, whitespace

I have a script on which the last line echos out the last line of a text file (minus the first 7 characters) to another file:

```
for /f "delims==" %%a in (c:\file1.txt) do set lastline=%%a
echo(%lastline:~7%> file2.txt
```

The lines look like this (I'm grabbing the name only with the above code):

> ```
> 4.53 - Billy
> 2.63 - Mark
> 12.42 - Tom
> ```

The problem is that if the last line starts with a two digit number before the decimal. The `echo` still works but the output includes the <kbd>SPACE</kbd> in between the `-` and the name because it is skipping 7 characters. I have to cater for both.

Is there a way to `echo` without including leading <kbd>SPACEs</kbd>? Or can I add a line afterwards which can remove all white-spaces from `file2.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not try to remove the leading SPACE, I would change the method of removing the number. Apply this to remove everything up to and including <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`-`<kbd>SPACE</kbd>:

```
echo(%lastline:* - =%> file2.txt
```

Or the better syntax:

```
> file2.txt echo(%lastline:* - =%
```

The latter variant is better in order to avoid trouble when the last character of the string to echo is a single numeral, separated from the rest by a token delimiter, because, together with the `>` symbol, it constitutes a [redirection operator](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html), like `2>`, for example.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, to remove leading white-spaces, use this:

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%L in ("%STRING%") do echo(%%L
```

This works, because the default delimiters of `for /F` are <kbd>SPACE</kbd> and <kbd>TAB</kbd>.